# Completable<Object> is returned while Completable<Void> is required

Tags: java

I have the following class of Person:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String city;
    public void setInfo(PersonInformation info) {//...};
}
```

I have a list of objects from this class and I want to populate their information asynchronously querying a db for each item in the list, using a method that returns CompletableFuture:

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> populateInformation(List<Person> people) {
     return people.stream().
            .collect(groupingBy(p -> p.getLocation(), toList()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> 
                    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                            () -> db.getPeopleInformation(entry.getKey())
                    ).thenApply(infoList -> { 
                                    //do something with info list that doens't return anything
                                    // apparently we HAVE to return null, as callanbles have to return a value
                                    return null;
                                }
                    )
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The problem is that I get a compilation error, because the code in the method returns `CompletableFuture<List<Object>>` instead of `CompletableFuture<List<Void>>`. What am I doing wrong here?

I thought of removing `return null`, but as I mentioned in the comment, it seems that in a callable we have to return a value, otherwise there would be another compilation error: `Incompatible types: expected not void but the lambda body is a block that is not value-compatible`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[thenApply](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) method return type is `CompletableFuture<U>`, which means returning CompletableFuture with value returned by function

```
public <U> CompletableFuture<U> thenApply(Function<? super T,? extends U> fn)
```

Returns a new `CompletionStage` that, when this stage completes normally, is executed with this stage's result as the argument to the supplied function. See the CompletionStage documentation for rules covering exceptional completion.

```
Type Parameters:
U - the function's return type

Parameters:
fn - the function to use to compute the value of the returned CompletionStage
```

Use [thenAccept](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-) method Which returns CompletableFuture of Void type

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> thenAccept(Consumer<? super T> action)
```

Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed with this stage's result as the argument to the supplied action. See the CompletionStage documentation for rules covering exceptional completion.

```
Parameters:
action - the action to perform before completing the returned CompletionStage
```

Answer (score 1):

[Answer by Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033356/5221149) is the right solution, but you can also force `thenApply` to return a `CompletableFuture<Void>` in two ways:

- Specify the generic type argument:

  ```
  ).<Void>thenApply(infoList -> {
  ```
- Cast the return value:

  ```
  return (Void) null;
  ```

You can of course do both, but that would be redundant.